# How to remove iPhone 4s and lower compatibility from Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, compatibility

iTunes Connect always asks me for 3.5 inch snapshots, how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  iPhone 4s still supports the latest iOS version, so you need to support it with your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can better place the scroll view so that it can be compatible with 4S .You can focus your design according as 5,5s & 6,6s. Width for 4s is same as 5,5s so it will work on it and for height user have to scroll to view the hidden views